# how to capture a photo and save in phone using opencv?

Tags: java, android, opencv

i am learning to write a object detection app
i want to capture a photo and save in phone when i click on a button

However,when it run to "Utils.matToBitmap(mRgba, newbitmap);"

the app crash!why?i do a research that mRgba is CV_8UC4,it should be able to do "matToBitmap"

here is my code

```
public void onCameraViewStarted(int width ,int height){
        mRgba=new Mat(height,width, CvType.CV_8UC4);
        
        mGray =new Mat(height,width,CvType.CV_8UC1);
    }
    public void onCameraViewStopped(){
        mRgba.release();
    }
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame){
        mRgba=inputFrame.rgba();
        mGray=inputFrame.gray();


        // now call that function
        Mat out=new Mat();
        out=objectDetectorClass.recognizeImage(mRgba);

        return out;
    }
    public void takePicture(View view) {
        // Create a Bitmap from the camera preview frame
        Bitmap newbitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mOpenCvCameraView.getWidth(), mOpenCvCameraView.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
       Utils.matToBitmap(mRgba, newbitmap);//app crash here




  // Save the bitmap to the device's gallery
       MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), newbitmap, "Image", "Image captured using Image");

    }
```

The error code is

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                                                        at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:6113)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7259)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7236)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:801)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27892)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
```